# Syntax for changing FancyBox close button into submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2, submit-button

What is the syntax for adding a helper function to FancyBox’s [FancyApps2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) `close` button that would turn it into a `submit` button?

I need to add the following:

```
input type="submit" 
name="whereto" 
value=""
```

Current FancyBox Function

```
$(function () {
  $(".fancybox_iframe").fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    padding: 0,
    scrolling: 'no',
    width: 840,
    minHeight: 150,
    height: 615,
    closeBtn: true,
    helpers: { overlay: { closeClick: false, opacity: .5} },
    afterShow: function () { $("a.fancybox-close").attr("title", null); },
    afterClose: function () {
        parent.close_field('notice');
        parent.closeiframe_redirect('index.php');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `afterShow` method of it:

```
afterShow: function () { 
   var input = $('<input />', {
       type : "submit",
       name : "whereto",
       value : ""
   });
   $("a.fancybox-close").replaceWith(input); 
},
```

Comment: `afterShow` is a callback, not a method ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an hidden submit button and jquery's trigger method?

http://jsfiddle.net/B6KE6/

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg">
    <img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>

<form style='display: none;' action='#?hey-it-works' method='get'>
    <input type='submit' class='fancysubmit' name='whereto' value='' />
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        padding: 0,
        scrolling: 'no',
        width: 840,
        minHeight: 150,
        height: 615,
        closeBtn: true,
        helpers: { overlay: { closeClick: false, opacity: 0.5} },
        afterShow: function () { $("a.fancybox-close").attr("title", null); },
        afterClose : function() {
            $(".fancysubmit").trigger('click');
            return;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make a submit button somewhere else, and then on `afterClose` use jQuery [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to trigger the button.